# Postgres recursive query for SSH authorized key paths

Tags: postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

How do I structure a recursive query to help me find all server-to-server jumps  that are accessible via SSH public key authorization?

For a given SSH pubkey fingerprint, first find the list of servers/accounts that the key is authorized for. For each server found, iterate over the private keys on that server, and find the list of servers/accounts that each of *those* are authorized for.

Repeat this process until there's a dead end, i.e. the authorized key path ends. Return a full authorized key path (as an array) per row.

### Simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE sshkeys (
  server         text, -- server UUID
  username       text, -- authorized username
  privkey_owner  text, -- owner of private key
  fingerprint    text, -- SSH key fingerprint
  keytype        text, -- "public" or "private"
)

Server  Username  Owner  Fingerprint         Keytype
banana  root             key_id_james        public
banana  james            key_id_james        public
banana            root   key_id_root@banana  private
apple   root             key_id_root@banana  public
apple   fred      fred   key_id_fred         private
mango   fred             key_id_fred         public
```

James, using his key with ID key_id_james, has access to root@banana. From there, the root@banana private key is authorized for root@apple. On apple, root can access key_id_fred, and is thus authorized for fred@mango.

So ultimately, James has access to Fred's account on mango, via root access to banana and apple. He also has access to james@banana. The two output rows would consist of arrays of {source, keyid, target} elements, looking something like:

```
{{NULL,   key_id_james,       root@banana},
 {banana, key_id_root@banana, root@apple},
 {apple,  key_id_fred,        fred@mango}},
{{NULL,   key_id_james,       james@banana}}
```

I plan to add restrictions and heuristics that should be taken into account, including whether private keys are encrypted and whether a given user has group or chmod access to another user's private key (by joining to other tables in the database). That should be easy to tack onto a working base query, however.

As for the query, I'm unable to figure out how to do the secondary step, that is: For each server initially found to be accessible via the given key, iterate over all private keys on each server and recurse. I'm not getting further than this non-working query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE initial_authkeys AS (
SELECT
  server, username, privkey_owner, fingerprint, keytype
FROM
  sshkeys
WHERE
  fingerprint = 'key_id_james' AND
  keytype = 'public'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  ak.server, ak.username, ak.privkey_owner, ak.fingerprint, ak.keytype
FROM
  sshkeys,
  initial_authkeys ak
WHERE
  sshkeys.fingerprint = ak.fingerprint AND
  sshkeys.keytype = 'private'
)
SELECT * FROM initial_authkeys;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's needed to make this work is a subquery expression to find the SSH fingerprints of any available private key on the server where the given pubkey is authorized. Below is a working query that includes a rudimentary heuristic to only find private keys if the user has root access to the server. It could be expanded to verify private key file permissions, group ownership, etc.

```
WITH RECURSIVE authkeys(server, username, fingerprint, level, auth_path) AS (
SELECT
  server, username, fingerprint, 1 AS level,
  ARRAY['Authorized to '||username||
  '@'||server||' using keyid='||fingerprint]
FROM
  sshkeys
WHERE
  fingerprint = 'key_id_james' AND keytype = 'public'
UNION
SELECT
  k.server, k.username, k.fingerprint, ak.level+1 AS level,
  auth_path || ARRAY['Authorized to '||k.username||
  '@'||k.server||' using keyid='||k.fingerprint]
FROM
  sshkeys k, authkeys ak
WHERE
  k.keytype = 'public' AND k.fingerprint IN (
    SELECT
      fingerprint
    FROM
      sshkeys k2
    WHERE
      k2.server = ak.server AND k2.keytype = 'private' AND
      ak.username = 'root'
  )
) SELECT * FROM authkeys;
```